# Install search provider/accelerator [Internet Explorer 8] remotely

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, search-engine

May I install a search provider/accelerator remotely in Internet Explorer 8?
I dont want to allow users choose, I want to install it in silent mode.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Hope [this](http://blogofanitadmin.blogspot.cz/2011/05/group-policy-changing-default-search.html) will help.